# View config getter callback for component `div` must be a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native

I'm new to React-Native and I'm trying to run the following code, however I keep getting this error:

> Invariant Violation: View config getter callback for component `div`
> must be a function (received `undefined`). Make sure to start
> component names with a capital letter.

```
export default function App() {

  console.log("this is a first run");
  
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <Text>This is my first app</Text>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.log("HEYY")}>
        <Image 
          source={{
          width:200, 
          height:200,
          uri: "https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300",
          }}
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

Thanks for the help (:

Comment: are you sure the error comes from this component? There is no div

Comment: Yes, I just found out the problem - 
I mistakenly imported "TouchbleOpacity" from 'react-native-web' instead of 'react-native'.

Comment: Shouldn't the styles object be in a `style` prop, separate from the `source` prop?